# Is "una dama vivida" a slang for "old car"? What alternative words does Spanish have for this?

Tags: coloquialismos, el-salvador

A friend from El Salvador reckoned an old car (i.e. one that's been around the block) is called *una dama vivida*, but I can't find any other reference to this. Does anyone know the slang for old car?

Un amigo mío en El Salvador me dijo que la jerga para un carro viejo es *una dama vivida* pero yo no encuentro una referencia. ¿Puedes confirmar o dame otras palabras/frases?

Comment: ¿Usted está buscando una lista de términos alternativos para "old car", o está preguntando si "una dama vivida" es un termino correcto en El Salvador?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La expresión desde luego no es universal. En España `Dama vivida` no tiene un significado como el que describes (ni ningún otro. Un español ante esa expresión te preguntaría si te refieres a una mujer de edad que se la ha pasado de fiesta en fiesta o algo similar).

En España (esto variará en otros países de habla hispana) el *slang* para `coche` (no decimos `carro` ni `auto`) es `buga`, pero esta expresión no designa necesariamente a un automóvil viejo. Si es muy viejo (y en mal estado) se le puede llamar `tartana`.

> Tíos, mirad mi nuevo *buga*!! A que *mola*!! (mostrando a los amigos un viejo coche de segunda mano)
>
> Pues... la verdad es que es una *tartana*. Es el coche que ya no usa tu abuela, verdad?

Por supuesto valen otras expresiones que valdrían para designar a otro tipo de maquinaria vieja, como *chatarra*, *cafetera*, *trasto*, etc.

Si es uno de esos coches antiguos pero en buen estado se les llama "coche antiguo" o "reliquia".

En [este enlace](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2700784) puedes encontrar algunas expresiones en otros lenguajes (posiblemente otros usuarios ayudarán a validar el uso de estas expresiones en sus países):

- "una viejera" de carro, o una "carcacha" (Colombia)
- "cascacho" y "carrindanga" (Argentina)
- "cachila" (Chile)
- "carcocha" (Perú)

Comment: Una nota adicional, cuando yo era pequeño (el siglo pasado) al viejo _Renault 5_ de mi padre le llamábamos "el **cuatro latas**", pero era más un chiste dentro de mi familia que una expresión de uso extendido.

Comment: Gracias. Tambien he encontrado armatoste y cacharro

Comment: +1 por "carcacha", que es la palabra que mas usamos en México para referirnos a un carro viejo.

Comment: Puntualizar que, si bien no es la palabra más utilizada, carro sí se usa en España.

Comment: El comentario de @Diego es viejisimo pero lo he visto ahora que ha subido esta publicación y solo quería decir que el "cuatro latas" era el Renault 4 no el 5.